# Method of conditional expectations for basket

Tags: stochastic-calculus, reference-request, expected-value, basket

I am reading paper "[An analysis of pricing methods for baskets options](https://www.semanticscholar.org/paper/An-analysis-of-pricing-methods-for-baskets-options-Krekel-Kock/a012b23a1f8fd7dc913e75e47fa74d246cf7148e)".

Unfortunatly, I can not find the working paper "Beisser, J. (1999): Another Way to Value Basket Options, Working paper, Johannes Gutenberg-Universität Mainz" in order to understand how to calculate adjusted forwards $\tilde{F}_i^T$ in the  "Beisser’s conditional expectation techniques" Section.

> **Beisser’s conditional expectation techniques**
>
> By conditioning on the random variable $Z$ and using Jensen’s
> inequality the price of the basket call is estimated by the weighted
> sum of (artificial) European call prices, more precisely
> $$
> \mathbb{E}([B(T) - K]^+) = \mathbb{E}(\mathbb{E}([B(T) - K]^+|Z)) \geq
> \mathbb{E}(\mathbb{E}([B(T) - K|Z]^+)) = \mathbb{E}(\sum^n_{i=1} w_i
> \mathbb{E}[S_i(T)|Z] - K)^+ $$
> where
> $$Z :=
> \frac{\sigma_z}{\sqrt{T}}W(T) = \sum^n_{i=1} w_i S_i(0)\sigma_i W_i(T)
> $$ with $\sigma_z$ appropriately chosen.  Note that in contradiction
> to $S_i(T)$, all conditional expectations $\mathbb{E}[S_i(T)|Z]$ are
> log-normally distributed with respect to one Brownian motion $W(T)$.
> Hence, there exists an $x'$, such that
> $$\sum^n_{i=1} w_i\mathbb{E}[S_i(T)|W(T) = x'] = K. $$
> By defining: $$ \tilde{K_i} :=\mathbb{E}[S_i(T)|W(T) = x'] $$ the event  $$ \sum^n_{i=1} w_i
> \mathbb{E}[S_i(T)|Z] \geq K $$
> is equivalent to $$\mathbb{E}[S_i(T)|Z] \geq \tilde{K}_i,  \forall  i = 1,2, \ldots, n.$$
>
> Using this argument we conclude that  $$\mathbb{E}(\sum^n_{i=1}
> w_i\mathbb{E}[S_i(T)|Z] - K)^+ = \sum^n_{i=1}
>  w_i\mathbb{E}([\mathbb{E}[S_i(T)|Z] - \tilde{K}_i]^+) = \sum^n_{i=1}
>  w_i[\tilde{F}^T_i N(d_{1i}) - \tilde{K}_i N(d_{2i})],$$  where
> $\tilde{F}^T_i$, $\tilde{K}_i$ adjusted forwards and strikes and
> $d_{1i}$, $d_{2i}$ are the usual terms with modified parameters.

**Question.** How to apply the conditional expectation techniques in order to calculate adjusted forwards $\tilde{F}_i^T$?

The price of a basket of
stocks as the weighted average of the prices of $n$ stocks at maturity $T$:
$$
B(T) =\sum^n_{i=1}
w_iS_i(T),
$$
$S_i(\cdot)$ - stock prices, $w_i$ - weights. $T$-forward price of stock $i$
$$
F_i^T = S_i(0) \exp\left( 
\int_0^T (r(s) - d_i(s))ds
\right),
$$
where $r(\cdot)$ and $d_i(\cdot)$ are deterministic interest rates and dividend yields.

I have found the [Lecture Notes](https://www.cs.ubc.ca/%7Enickhar/W12/Lecture16Notes.pdf) with the method of conditional expectations but can not apply this method to the problem.

Comment: Have you tried contacting the author? https://www.hs-rm.de/de/hochschule/personen/beisser-jochen

Comment: @BobJansen, not yet. I wrote the letter to the author of paper. Thanks for idea.